# Why isnt my VBA code working on excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I am at my wits end with this. I am pretty sure my logic is correct and i have defined everything properly and followed the syntax. Also, there is no error showing up for this chunk of code. Please please please take a look at it and let me know why it is not working. I just started to learn this and i am really looking for help.

```
Sub AddMN()

'declare the variables

    Dim MNFX As String
    Dim MNDO As String
    Dim FXDO As String
    Dim OPT As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lastEmpty As Integer

    FXDO = Sheet3.Range("F3")
    OPT = Sheet3.Range("H3")


    Sheet6.Activate

    For i = 2 To 1000
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
            lastEmpty = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    If FXDO = "FIXED" And OPT = "YES" Then

       Cells(lastEmpty, 1).Select
       Sheet5.Range("MNFX").Copy
       ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

    ElseIf FXDO = "DRAWOUT" And OPT = "YES" Then

       Cells(lastEmpty, 1).Select
       Sheet5.Range("MNDO").Copy
       ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

    End If

    With Sheet6.Columns
       .WrapText = False
       .AutoFit
    End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: You've not told us what your code is supposed to do or in what way it's *not working*. How specifically would you like us to help you? We can't read your mind or see your screen. Please [edit] your question to make it clear what you're asking, and ask a specific question that we can answer (other than "Why isn't this working?").

Comment: You're more likely to get useful help if you tell us what behavior you currently get and what you expect.

Comment: Hi AF786. Welcome to SO. Thank you for taking the time to post the code. It would be helpful to understand what the code is intended to do, and what it is actually doing that you did not expect.

Answer (score -1):

Your usage of 'IsEmpty' function is wrong.

IsEmpty checks a Variant-type variable is initialized or not, so argumet of 'IsEmpty' should be a Variant.

In your code, argumet of 'IsEmpty' is (Cells(i, 1).Value). That is not a variant, so IsEmpty returns 'FALSE' anytime.

As the result, the variable 'lastEmpty' is 0 (initial value).  This is the problem of your code, I guess.

To fix this problem, following part of your code

```
For i = 2 To 1000
    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
        lastEmpty = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

should be corrected as

```
For i = 2 To 1000
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
        lastEmpty = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

This correction makes your code works, I hope.

Comment: Hi Fumu. Thanks for your response. Your method works too but so does mine. I am grateful for your response

Comment: Should be `If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then`

Answer (score -2):

You Have put the sheets in as Sheet6.blah blah when it should be Sheets("Sheet6").Blah Blah

I have made a few streamlines to your code for you, try this:

```
Sub AddMN()

'declare the variables

Dim MNFX As String
Dim MNDO As String
Dim FXDO As String
Dim OPT As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastEmpty As Integer

FXDO = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("F3")
OPT = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("H3")
Sheets("Sheet6").Activate
lastEmpty = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
If FXDO = "FIXED" And OPT = "YES" Then
   Sheets("Sheet5").Range("MNFX").Copy
   Cells(lastEmpty, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
ElseIf FXDO = "DRAWOUT" And OPT = "YES" Then
   Sheets("Sheet5").Range("MNDO").Copy
   Cells(lastEmpty, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End If

With Sheets("Sheet6").Columns
   .WrapText = False
   .AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your response. The method i use also works and so does yours. I am not sure if there are specific moments where only yours would work but i am sure mine works for now.

Comment: Both Sheet6.blah blah and Sheets("Sheet6").Blah Blah are valid. Check out http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-vba-sheet-names.htm and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837552.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396